# MySQL can't use ORDER BY on concatenated columns

Tags: mysql

I'm studying mySQL.
I must have to use `'ORDER BY F"` (It's homework), but I can't.
How do I modify my code?

```
SELECT CONCAT(F,' ', L,' ') name, COUNT(R) NumOfR
FROM E join d ON E.S1 = d.S2
WHERE R ='a' OR R = 'b'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY F;
```

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column 'c.E.F' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1):

As of MySQL 5.7.5, the default SQL mode includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BΥ

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

> Reject queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER
>   BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the
>   GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined
>   by) GROUP BY columns.

So you should either

```
ORDER BY name
```

which is equivalent as ordering by F since name is the concatenated result of F and L.

OR

```
ORDER BY ANY_VALUE(F)
```

to tell MySQL that it can use any F value from each name group

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value